# Partially ordered? Transitive closure?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

$\bullet$ Question A is:

We are given $R = \{(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 4)\}$.

It is reflexive because $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,3)$, $(4,4)$ is in the set.

It is antisymmetric because $(b,a)$ is not in the set for any of the pairs.

It is not transitive because $(1,1)$ is missing from the set.

Is this correct?

$\bullet$ Question B is:

Given the relation $S = \{(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (4, 2)\}$.

Name the transitive closure $\hat{S}$ of $S$.

So we must also have $(2,1)\in\hat{S}$ and $(1,3)\in\hat{S}$.

$\bullet$ Remark:

$R$ is said to be transitive, if:

$(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, a) \in R \Rightarrow (a, c) \in R$,

Comment: Isn't $(1,1)$ the element you listed first (and that you just claimed to be in there a second time)?

Comment: The first relation is actually transitive.  As for the second relation, the transitive closure is missing quite a bit, but $(2,1)$ is not one of the things missing.  By my count, I see four pairs missing from the relation to make it transitive.

Comment: Alright.

"Lets recall the definition of transitivity. A relation R⊆A×A on A is called transitive, if we have
(a,b),(b,c)∈R⇒(a,c)
for all a,b,c∈A."


So we get R_1 = (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (2, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (2, 1), (4, 1) for our closure.

Comment: And if we see a (2, 2) in the set, do we then find other members of the set to pair it up with?

Comment: I don't see why $(4,1)$ should be in the transitive closure of the second one, though $(1,4)$ should be. Another thing you should take into consideration is that you could have $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R$, meaning the transitive closure would include $(a,a)$.